# Rails3 Why is my HTTP_COOKIE getting escaped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Some time when i try to read HTTP_COOKIES e.g. env["HTTP_COOKIE"] this string is encoded. Can anyone explain me what could be the possible reasons?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RoR use cookies to store the session by default. Also the content is encrpyted. More info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage). To access cookie information use [ActionController::Cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

Comment: but this does not happen every time. only Some times I get escaped cookie.

Comment: It's look like i do not understood you correctly. What did you mean with encoded? ... encoded like in url encoded, encrypted like in AES encrypted, escaped like in string escaping, other maybe?